# Why is fpectl — Floating point exception control so dangerous?

Tags: python, exception

I was reading about `fpectl` — Floating point exception control in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fpectl.html).

It warns users that

> ......and its usage is discouraged and may be dangerous except in the hands of experts. See also the section Limitations and other considerations on limitations for more details.

**Why?**

Reading the linked webpage did not help me.

Comment: Most notably: `Setting up a given processor to trap IEEE-754 floating point errors currently requires custom code on a per-architecture basis. ` and `The fpectl module is not thread-safe.` Different architecture handles floating point numbers differently and therefor requires customization of the exceptions themselves.

Comment: It's also basically broken and unmaintained at this point. See [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-January/147094.html).

Comment: `fpectl` was removed in Python 3.7 https://bugs.python.org/issue29137

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For many reasons, it's unsafe in the way that "not driving defensively" is unsafe. You might do it and have no trouble whatever. Or you might get unlucky and run off the road, across the median, and into oncoming traffic.

Just a few reasons why it's chaotic at best, and difficult to reason about in a way that makes using it to create safe, reliable code extremely difficult:

1. It's not thread-safe. Meaning it will act differently in a threaded
   vs. non-threaded program, and probably differently in a different way
   in just about every threaded program.
2. Its support code needed and behavior can vary widely based on the 
   specific floating point implementation. So if you get your code working
   right on one, that doesn't mean you can distribute that code
   safety to other systems, or other users who might run it on
   different a CPU family (e.g. ARM vs x86 vs POWER), or different 
   generations of the same CPU family (e.g. AMD vs Intel 
   implementations of x86).
3. Floating point code is remarkably portable in the 
   [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) era. But there
   are still subtle imperfections that 
   those doing 
   [numerical algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis)
   take cautions to prevent. Understanding boundary
   conditions, how floating point approximations 
   behave (or fail to behave) at those edges, 
   and how different FP implementations handle them is still 
   important. Reducing variables is
   a key way of restricting risk in writing those algorithms.
   Using a poorly-understood, poorly-documented, rarely-used,
   not-part-of-standard-Python
   exception handling module is the opposite of
   "reducing risk."
4. The risk involves data integrity. It's possible that squelching
   exceptions will let bad or inconsistent data into your further
   calculations.
   Exceptions are like pain.
   Systemic signals something's wrong or "don't do that!" 
   Turning them off has a long history in numerical processing
   of leading to uncaught data corruption. In this age of widespread
   `NaN` and `Inf` support, that's less likely than in ages past,
   since there are in-band (in the data values) signaling mechanisms
   that can be alternate indicators.  But without studying the
   source code, do you really know what happens to the data in
   place of a `OverflowError`? Can you guarantee it will be the same
   outcome if it's processed in a vector or scalar FP instruction ?
   Doubtful. 
   Will your code know the difference
   between a `NaN` that results from squelched numerical exceptions
   vs a run-of-the-mill missing datum? Probably not. So many new
   uncertain outcomes!
5. The documentation itself basically warns "you're going to need to 
   drop down and study the source code to see how this really works."
   That is a significant, triple-black-diamond path. 
   They don't enable it in the standard builds for a reason.
   If you don't 
   already understand the numerical analysis dos-and-don'ts of traveling
   it, it's not for you.